# Is it possible to remove OAT files for unwanted system apps? [rooted locked device]

Tags: insufficient-memory, system-apps, bloatware, dalvik

I have not enough free space on my Moto X, so I want to free up some space in data partition used by system <strike>apps</strike> bloatware. For example, disabled Slides with uninstalled updates still consumes 31 MB of space (App=Total storage usage, not data). 27 MB of it is OAT file in `/data/dalvik-cache` folder. I'm trying to delete that file in way that does not trigger its recreation by ART on next boot. But even replacing OAT file with blank file triggers recompilation. And using `pm uninstall --user 0` command also didn't help.

And I have no idea, what is remaining 4 MB.

I have rooted, but locked Android 5.1 device (and unable to unlock – AT&T Moto X). Xposed FW installed.

Does exist way to delete permanently these OAT files of unused system apps?
Best thing occurred to me is that I can delete these files by script after every start, but it would mean huge penalization of boot time every boot.

Thanks for response.